# Wifi keeps disconnecting randomly and won't come back till restarting system

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager

My wifi keeps getting disconnected randomly. Once disconnected, switching it off and on from the GUI (Settings) doesn't do any good. After disconnection, turning it off says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" in the GUI settings. If I try to turn it on, it keeps searching for a network, and is unable to find one.

When it gets disconnected, it keeps being connected to the network (visible with the wifi symbol with a question mark) but no internet access is there.

Running `sudo lshw -C network` gives this:

```bash
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 31
       serial: 5c:ea:1d:3d:25:e9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 memory:df000000-df1fffff
```

I've tried doing these:

1. `sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 up`; Gives `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error`
2. `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager`; Nothing happens
3. `rfkill list`; Gives:

```bash
0: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

4. `rfkill unblock all` does nothing.

I am using this system:

```bash
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.